# Django error when migrations or migrate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When execute `python manage.py makemigrations` or `python manage.py migrate` I see the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/home/ubuntu/mywasi-root/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
  File "/home/ubuntu/mywasi-root/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.exceptions import MigrationSchemaMissing
  File "/home/ubuntu/mywasi-root/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .migration import Migration, swappable_dependency  # NOQA
ImportError: No module named 'django.db.migrations.migration'
```

Why I see this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Check if your Django installation is complete. You should not see this error if it is.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: reinstall Django.

Using `pip3 uninstall django` and then `pip3 install django` it works now!